# Duvida Alerta em Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estava procurando uma função para exibir uma mensagem de alerta ao usuário quando ele sair da página e localizei essa aqui no fórum:

```
<script>
   // Script de Alerta ao fechar a pagina... 
   window.onbeforeunload = fecharJanela 

   function fecharJanela(){  
      return "Você realmente deseja sair? os dados não salvos serão perdidos..."; 
   } 
</script>
```

Como fazer para esse alerta não ser executado quando eu realizar um submit?

O problema está acontecendo por que o sistema que estou desenvolvendo está realizando um *refresh* na página ai ao clicar no botão que envia os dados o navegador está exibindo a mensagem

Complementando a Postagem....
Vejam a imagem, a mensagem de alerta é exibida quando eu clico em "alterar" queria que ela não fosse exibida quando clicasse nesse botão

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: faltou você colocar a mensagem na pergunta

Comment: Que mensagem? Fazer a submissão através de `isset($_POST)`? Essa frase não fez sentido. Fazer o alerta não ser executado? Como assim? No geral, sua pergunta fez sentido nenhum. Pode [edit] e tentar melhorá-la, descrevendo melhor o problema?

Comment: complementei com uma imagem! é exibido um alerta no navegador..

Comment: crie um boolean, e só execulte a função do alert se esse boolean for true ou false depende da sua lógica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o teu botão deve ter algum *hiperlink* ou **submit** para sair da pagina atual o que faz sentido.

Para resolveres esta problema basta anulares a função `onbeforeunload` no  evento `onclick` do botão:

```
document.getElementById('alterar').onclick = function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
};
```

Ou podes mesmo associar no HTML, exemplo:

```
<button type="submit" id="alterar" onclick="window.onbeforeunload = null;">Alterar</button>
```

Comment: obrigado! coloquei o informado no onclick e funcionou

Answer (score 1):

Se existe um botão então defina o `window.onbeforeunload` para `null` quando ele for clicado, assim o alerta não será exibido.

Não faz sentido querer fazer isso como `isset($_POST[]))`, isso é PHP, enquanto o alerta está já no cliente, no Javascript.

---

Isso funcionará:

```
SeuElemento.addEventListener("click", function(){
    window.onbeforeunload = null;

    //... Resto do código do botão
});
```

---

[Teste aqui.](https://jsfiddle.net/3dneaka0/show/) <sub>[(código)](https://jsfiddle.net/3dneaka0/)</sub>

Comment: obrigado pela dica! não quero fazer via PHP, na verdade coloquei o isset[$_POST] para mostrar como estou enviando os dados via Submit...

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  return 'Blá Blá Blá';
}

function enviar()
{
   window.onbeforeunload = null;
   return true;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="enviar()">
</form>
```

Você pode adicionar uma condição na sua function ou limpar o evento window.onbeforeunload.

Exemplo de remover o evento:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Exemplo de condição:

```
<script>
   // Script de Alerta ao fechar a pagina... 
   window.onbeforeunload = function(){  

     if(isFormSubmit)
        return;

     return "Você realmente deseja sair? os dados não salvos serão perdidos..."; 
   } 
</script>
```